# Python3 class decorator which receives types as parameters is implicitly calling the constructors of those types

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, decorator, python-packaging

I am writing a bot in python, and I am writing some neat code for dynamically loading and registering certain classes as "Command" classes. One of the way I am doing this is by decorating these classes as a `@bot_command`. If the command has subcommands (other classes), I allow the option to provide their types as parameters to the `@bot_command` decorator. For example, I have a `help` command, which does not have any subcommands:

```py
@bot_command
class Help(Command):
    ...
```

And I have a `role` command which *does* have subcommands:

```py
@bot_command(Create, Delete, Join, Leave, List)
class Role(Command):
    ...
```

I have some code to detect these classes, and then create an instance of them. The instance then registers itself as a command via the decorator. Here is the code for the decorator:

```py
def bot_command(cmd: Type[Command], *subcommands: Type[Command]) -> Type[Command]:
    original_init = cmd.__init__

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        original_init(self)
        # If the command is not a subcommand
        if type(cmd.parent) == Command:
            registry.register_top_level_command(self)
        else:
            parents = []
            parent = cmd.parent
            # Gather all of this subcommand's parent commands
            while type(parent) != Command:
                parents.append(parent.name)
                parent = parent.__class__.parent
            registry.register_subcommand(parents, self)
        for sub in subcommands:
            sub.parent = self
            cmd.subcommands.append(sub())

    cmd.__init__ = __init__

    return cmd
```

As you can see, all the decorator does is inject some code into the Command's constructor, but the code shouldn't get executed until the Command's constructor is called. The way I do this is by importing all of the modules containing the top-level commands and constructing one of each. Based on the code in the decorator, the constructor should be able to detect its own subcommands and construct them, and their constructors will register themselves.

When I instantiate `Help`, it registers itself as expected. However, when I just load the module containing `Role`, it breaks because its subcommands attempt to construct themselves before they are supposed to. I believe this is tied to the decorator for whatever reason. The stack trace is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adam/dev/memebot/src/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from memebot import MemeBot
  File "/home/adam/dev/memebot/src/memebot.py", line 5, in <module>
    import commands
  File "/home/adam/dev/memebot/src/commands/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    dynamically_register_commands()
  File "/home/adam/dev/memebot/src/commands/__init__.py", line 20, in dynamically_register_commands
    pkg = importlib.import_module(f"commands.{pkg_name}")
  File "/home/adam/.anaconda3/envs/memebot/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/adam/dev/memebot/src/commands/role/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    class Role(Command):
  File "/home/adam/dev/memebot/src/commands/command.py", line 119, in __init__
    registry.register_top_level_command(self)
  File "/home/adam/dev/memebot/src/commands/registry.py", line 56, in register_top_level_command
    raise KeyError(f"Command {command.name} already registered.")
KeyError: 'Command create already registered.'
```

The line that sticks out to me is

```
File "/home/adam/dev/memebot/src/commands/role/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    class Role(Command):
```

because it implies that the subcommands are attempting to be constructed at class-load time. This shouldn't happen, as their constructors are only called in the parent's constructor, which hasn't been called yet. I also tested my hypothesis by removing the subcommands from `Role`'s decorator as such:

```
@bot_command  # (Create, Delete, Join, Leave, List)
class Role(Command):
    ...
```

This modification caused the `Role` command to load perfectly, although it had no way of calling its subcommands.

Another strange thing which I cannot explain but might provide more context about what is happening is that the `Create` command is constructed and registers itself before the `Role` command, which leads the registry to believe that `Create` is a top-level command. This is the direct cause of failure, because for some reason, `Create` attempts to register itself a second time and the registry throws because of this.

Can anybody explain the behavior of decorators and how this particular use of a decorator would cause this behavior? I was led to believe that decorators run only once at module-load time, which was my main motivation for using them.

Comment: Are you expecting `@func(a, b, c)` above `class Foo: ...` to run `func(Foo, a, b, c)`? It runs `func(a, b, c)(Foo)`.

Comment: a decorator called with arguments should be a decorator factory, it returns a decorator that accepts the func or class as its sole argument

Comment: You two seem to be correct in your diagnosis of my issue and how to fix it. I suppose I didn't understand decorators as well as I thought  Thanks for your help!